# Infopath form publishing and root content type?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I have several infopath 2010 form template that I want to publish to a form library in SharePoint 2010 Server with enterprise CaL.
All of this forms have a common part (a template part actually). Is it possible to define a common "parent" content type of this forms ?

In fact, I want :

- Form content type (SP OOB)

  - My root form content type, with standard columns "requester", "process name", etc.

    - Form 1
    - Form 2
    - etc.
  - other unrelated form 1
  - other unrelated form 2

Instead of the standard behavior :

- Form content type (SP OOB)

  - Form 1
  - Form 2
  - other unrelated form 1
  - other unrelated form 2
  - etc.

Behind this question I want to be able to create a dashboard of all form request using a content query web, by **simply** specifying the content type ... In fact, I want to display the content of the common part in a view for all forms (state, etc.).

One last word: the idea is to allow a customer (assuming its knowledge is limited to IP 2010 basic form design). So I can't accept answers like "extract files, use a text editor and hack the xsf file"...

thx in advance

Comment: Hi Steve, are you publishing the forms using Microsoft InfoPath or custom code?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to specify that in InfoPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft InfoPath (the application) to publish, you will not be able to specify that. From my experience, Microsoft InfoPath abstracts all that away from you so you don't even have to know about it.